# php Strict Standards: Creating default object from empty value

Tags: php

i am getting this error on every page where i am trying to get any kind of id  for instance i am using the following code

```
$objClass = array();
$objClass[0]->custId = $_GET['id'];
```

i am getting error in the second line. though it is working fine but it just keeps on showing everywhere. I read the answer with stdclass but i dint get it so if ur giving this as a solution plz explain hw to use it cz im quite new in the field.
also can somebody tell me how to hide php errors.

Comment: Are you sure it's working fine? What is the error message you are seeing? Silencing them isn't addressing the issue.

Comment: You probably want to check isset( $_GET['id'] ) first.  Your text-style abbreviations makes me sad :(.  plz use please?

Comment: yeah it is working fine, i am using that $objClass[0] object later to update my customer's record. so it seems to be working fine but these errors are appearing on every page where i am using customer id or item id.
@amccausl i am sorry for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually declare the object. You need to use

```
$objClass[0] = new stdClass;
```

First

Answer (score 2):

From the snippet you've given I think what you're trying to achieve is this, no need for arrays:

```
$objClass = new stdClass();
$objClass->custId = $_GET['id'];
```

Don't forget you should be filtering the input from $_GET for security.

Don't turn error warnings off, they show you things that need to be addressed in your code.