# include in php function

Tags: php, function, templates, include

I'm writing PHP code, where I have function, in this function I have include, it works fine but I get error if I'm write new code in this include file

Error:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: text
```

Function:

```
function inc($templateinc){
    if(file_exists(Fsys.Fview.$templateinc)){
        include Fsys.Fview.$templateinc;
    }
    else {
        include Fsys.Fview.'errors/404.php';
    }
}
```

Where I'm printing function:

```
$text = "text";
inc("main/index.php");
```

main/index.php file:

```
echo $text;
```

How can I fix this problem?

Thank you

Comment: Problem solved! I'm add global $tpl; in function and I'm add this in template:

$tpl["giorgi"] = "Giorgi";
$tpl["bulia"] = "Bulia"; Thank you All!

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
inc("main/index.php");
```

try

```
include_once("main/index.php");
```

Comment: I need to use function, Thank you for reply

Answer (score 0):

```
   function inc($templateinc,$data){
    if(file_exists(Fsys.Fview.$templateinc)){
        include Fsys.Fview.$templateinc;
    }
    else {
        include Fsys.Fview.'errors/404.php';
    }
}

        $data=array();

    $data['title']='Some title...';
    $data['text']='This is page content...';

    $data['array']=array(1,2,3,4);



        inc('test.php',$data);
```

test.php:

```
 echo $data['title'];

echo $data['text'];

foreach ($data['array'] as $var) {

    echo $var;

}
```

So, $data ($text) should be passed as argument in your function.

Comment: thank you for replay, now its works, but i have many variables and when it many I can't add all of variable. Thank you

Comment: @GiorgiBulia, make array, and place variables in array.

Comment: I does not know how to make it. Now I'm add global $text; in this function and I'm try to make this: $text->giorgi = "Giorgi"; $text->bulia = "Bulia"; now it printed but in header I get this error:  Strict Standards: Creating default object from empty value. thank you!

Comment: You will need associative array, or, probably, even multidimensional array (array combined of arrays; depending on site complexity). '->' sign is for accessing object properties and methods. You didn't created object, probably: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8863201/php-strict-standards-creating-default-object-from-empty-value

Comment: @GiorgiBulia, please see updated answer... If you want object oriented approach, you will need class, objects, etc, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what are you trying to achieve.
Just put `$text = "text";` inside main/index.php
and change the code to `inc("main/index.php"); 
echo $text;`

Basically, `$text` is not defined inside that index.php

Comment: I think that Giorgi try to make some kind of framework/mvc pattern, and that he wants the way to pass variables to the view?

Comment: I'm trying to make model & view, in view i need template (html) and in model i need script. Thank you for reply